# Cannot get object’s property in state before render using Vue + Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vuex store with an object called data in the state of a module called users. This object maps user ids to users, and it begins empty.

Then I have a message-list component that renders message components with a passed property called authorId. This message will use the id try to get the author's email by searching the data object in the store. If it doesn't find it, it will dispatch an action that will fetch the user from the server and commit a mutation to add the id and user to the data object in the store. Note that for now every message has the same authorId and that the server fetching logic works as expected.

**Users module**

```
state: { data: {} },
mutations: {
  setUser(state, user) {
    Vue.set(state.data, user._id, user);
  },
},
actions: {
  fetchUser({ commit }, id) {
    userService.find({ _id: id }).then((response) => {
      commit('setUser', response.data[0]);
    });
  }
```

**Message component**

```
<template>
<div class="message">
  <strong v-if="author">{{author.email}}</strong>: {{text}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'messages',
  props: ['text', 'authorId'],
  created() {
    this.resolveAuthor();
  },
  computed: {
    author() {
      return this.$store.state.users.data[this.authorId];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    resolveAuthor() {
      if (!this.author) this.$store.dispatch('fetchUser', this.authorId);
  },
};
</script>
```

The expected behaviour would be to see just one setUser mutation because the first message component instance will fetch and populate the store, and the next instances would use that stored value. I see one mutation per message meaning that the call to this.author in created() or mounted() is always undefined, maybe I would expect this in the first message but not in the next ones as the store is already populated.

Doing console.log(Object.keys(this.$store.state.users.data)) in every created() or mounted() of each message instance reveals the data object is empty but I can see it has one key (authorId) and the user value in the vue dev-tools and also if I console.log(this.$store.state.users.data).

Moreover, if in the template I render {{this.user}} it will print the data correctly on every message. Also if I re-save any file, hot reloading will now print all the console.log(Object.keys(this.$store.state.users.data)) I did before again but now showing the key and value I expect instead of showing an empty object.

**Edit 2018-10-24**
I hope that the working repository helps someone: https://github.com/niklabaz/chatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got a race condition there. You're looping and creating components and then when you create every component (message) you want to get user that created msg. Now I think what's happening is you create first component and it doesn't detect user in data so it tries to fetch it but before that user is gotten through the api ( it takes time even if it's a couple of ms) you render another component and data.users is still not filled and it dispatches another api request. Remember vue will not wait for one api request to return data  to render another component in a loop. If this is true and I'm correct you'll need to restructure your component structure or at least fetch users in a different way.

**edit**

My suggestion would be to tinker with your server side code so it sends a user object ( or at least their uname and id ) as a part of every message object. Even if you don't use ORM you can join msg table that has user_id FK with users table. Then you fetch all this data in parent component and then when you loop through messages you'll have all user info you need.

Comment: I though this too, so I tried making the action return a promise and in the resolveAuthor() I would dispatch the action and .then() associate a local property called authorEmail to the one in the store (given that the fetch operation finished successfully). In this case, Vue would have to wait for this message to fetch in order to render the next ones right? But I see the same behavior happen.

Comment: No, if you return a promise from an action it you can chain .then on it in the place you dispatched the action. So `this.$store.dispatch ('action', id).then((res) => // js will wait for response here )` but rendering another msg component has nothing to do with this... when rendering components in a loop promise you're returning doesn't stop the loop.

Comment: That's the problem probably. If in the parent component instead of doing <Message v-for=...> I do <div v-for="msg in messages"> and inside this div I check if the author it's available and fetch it if needed (with a promise) then the looping should pause or that wouldn't be a solution?

Comment: And even if the store isn't available when messages are rendered, they should be updated once the store is populated because they use reactive properties.

Comment: The thing is I have to show an avatar too, so attaching an image url and user email to every message i'ts not that great given that there would be repeated data everywhere. I'll resort to it if nothing else works anyway,

Comment: Then try getting all users for all messages you're trying to display and store them and then just get them as you need them.